# Find a specific character and change the record to null

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I'm loading some data using SSIS, need to find a specific character(P) and change the record(that contains the character) to null. Any idea?

The data comes like:

- P47625671654
- PH234598
- PGG654

but it should show:

- NULL
- NULL
- NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a derived column using the following expression:

```
FINDSTRING([Column],"P",1) > 0 ? NULL(DT_WSTR,50) : [Column]
```